# How can I get use cuda inside a gitlab-ci docker executor

Tags: docker, cuda, gitlab

We are using gitlab continuous integration to buildand test our projects. Recently, one of the projects added the requirement for CUDA to enable GPU acceleration. I do not want to change our pipeline (docker and gitlab-ci are working well for us), so I'd like to somehow give docker the ability to talk to an nvidia GPU.

Additional details:

- Installing an nvidia GPU on our build servers is fine - we have some spare GPU's lying around to use for that purpose
- We are not using ubuntu or centOS, so we cannot use [nvidia's cuda containers](https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda/) directly
- You can't supply the `--runtime` parameter to gitlab CI, so you can't use nvidia's suggested docker invocation. [ edit: actually, you can now. See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/merge_requests/764 ]

Answer (score 4):

There is now the `--gpu` flag on gitlab runner versions  >13.9. You should use those insetad. If stuck with older versions, read on.

---

There are multiple steps:

1. Install the nvidia driver on the host PC
2. Install nvidia-docker2
3. Build a docker image with CUDA
4. Get it working in gitlab CI

Note that if you only want to compile CUDA code and don't need to run it, you don't need to use nvidia-docker2, have the nvidia driver on the host PC, and there are no special steps for getting it working in gitlab CI. (ie you only have to do step 3)

I'm afraid I'm not too familiar with docker, so if I've mixed container and image I apologize. If someone with more knowledge wants to fix any typos about docker, it would be greatly appreciated.

### Step 1: Install the nvidia driver on the host PC

YOu have two options here. Either you can use your host's OS's recommended procedure. This is easy, but will mean that the environment may differ across build servers.
The other option is to download the installer directly from nVidia (ie https://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html ) so that you can distribute that with your docker container.

### Step 2: Install nvidia-docker2

My current test PC is archlinux, so this was a case of using it from the AUR. nVidia provides repositories for several OS's, so see the quickstart guide on the [nvidia-docker](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) github page.

You should test your nvidia-docker installation as per the quickstart guide. Running from your host PC the command:
`docker run --runtime=nvidia --rm nvidia/cuda:9.0-base nvidia-smi` should run and output something like:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 415.18       Driver Version: 415.18       CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 106...  Off  | 00000000:02:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 28%   39C    P0    24W / 120W |    350MiB /  6071MiB |      3%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Notice that although I've specified the 9.0-base image, nvidia-smi reports Cuda 10. I think this is because Cuda 10 is installed on the host PC. The nvidia-docker documentation says that it will use cuda from the docker image, so this shouldn't be a problem.

### Step 3: Build a docker image with CUDA

You should use the Nvidia dockerhub docker images directly unless you have a good reason not to. In my case, I wanted to use a docker image based on Debian, but Nvidia only provides images for Ubuntu and CentOS. Fortunately, Nvidia posts the dockerfile for their images, so you can copy the relevant part of their dockerfiles from them. I based mine on https://gitlab.com/nvidia/cuda/blob/ubuntu16.04/9.2/base/Dockerfile

The magic part of the dockerfile included:

```
# Install cuda manually
RUN wget https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/9.2/Prod2/local_installers/cuda_9.2.148_396.37_linux

COPY install_cuda.exp install_cuda.exp
RUN mv cuda_* cuda_install_bin && \
    chmod +x cuda_install_bin && \
    expect install_cuda.exp && \
    rm cuda_*

# Magic copied from nvidia's cuda9.2 dockerfile at
# https://gitlab.com/nvidia/cuda/blob/ubuntu16.04/9.2/base/Dockerfile
ENV CUDA_VERSION 9.2.148


LABEL com.nvidia.volumes.needed="nvidia_driver"
LABEL com.nvidia.cuda.version="${CUDA_VERSION}"

RUN echo "/usr/local/nvidia/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia.conf && \
    echo "/usr/local/nvidia/lib64" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia.conf

ENV PATH /usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:${PATH}
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64

# nvidia-container-runtime
ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES all
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES compute,utility
ENV NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA "cuda>=9.2"
```

The "expect" command is will allow you to write a script to automatically accept the license agreement etc. automatically. It's probably not a good idea for me to post the `install_cuda.exp` file (because I can't accept the agreement for you), but in my case I accepted the eula, agreed to install it on an unsupported OS, did *not* install the graphics driver, did install cuda, used the default path, installed a symlink to usr/local/cuda and did not install the samples.
For more information on expect, see the man page [[online man page here]](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).
The inspect file is mostly made up of lines like `expect --  "(y)es/(n)o/(q)uit:" { send "y\r" }`

You should check you can run nvidia-smi test command for nvidia-smi using your own container. (ie `docker run --runtime=nvidia -it your_image_here /bin/sh`)

### Step 4: Get it running inside gitlab-ci.

When researching around the web, most sources tell you that you can't supply the `--runtime` flag from gitlab runner configuration. Actually, according to this [merge request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/merge_requests/764), you can. To do so, you have to edit `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` and add in `runtime = "nvidia"` to the right place.
For example, my runner configuration looks like:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "docker-runner-test"
  url = "<<REDACTED>>"
  token = "<<REDACTED>>"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "build_machine"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    runtime = "nvidia"
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    pull_policy = "never"
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
```

Comment: Has anyone tested this?

Comment: Yes, I have set up following these directions on Arch, Debian and Ubuntu Server hosts. The build machines produce a couple builds daily and the program requires CUDA in order to execute. If you have issues, drop a comment.

Answer (score 2):

The `--gpus all` argument is supported by GitLab Runners since version 13.9:

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/gpus.html

Answer (score 0):

For the record, if anyone stumbles on this issue, since docker `19.03` contains native support for GPUs in the docker client, this method [is now deprecated](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker).

However, at the time of writing, gitlab-runner [does not support yet](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/4585) this new API.

I've checked, and the old method still works for now, even if it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [GitLab 13.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/02/22/gitlab-13-9-released/#gpu-and-smart-scheduling-support-for-gitlab-runner) (February 2021):

> ### GPU and smart scheduling support for GitLab Runner
>
> Specialized compute workloads like those used in machine learning can significantly benefit from access to GPUs.
> Developers can configure GitLab Runner to leverage GPUs in the Docker executor by forwarding the `--gpu` flag.
>
> You can also use this with recent support in [GitLab’s fork of Docker Machine](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker_machine.html#using-the-forked-version-of-docker-machine), which allows you to [accelerate workloads with attached GPUs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/create-vm-with-gpus).
> Doing so can help control costs associated with potentially expensive machine configurations.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker_machine.html#using-gpus-on-google-compute-engine) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4585).

---

And with [GitLab 16.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/05/22/gitlab-16-0-released/#gpu-enabled-saas-runners-on-linux) (May 2023):

> ### GPU-enabled SaaS runners on Linux
>
> We are aiming to bring the best practices of DevSecOps to data sciences by providing more powerful compute hardware within GitLab runner.
> Previously, data scientists may have had workloads that were compute-intensive and as a result, jobs may not have been as quickly executed in GitLab.
>
> Now, with GPU-enabled SaaS runners on Linux, these workloads can be seamlessly supported using GitLab.com.
>
> So why wait? Try out the new runner today and let us know what you think in this [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/403008). We can’t wait to hear your feedback!
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_0/gpu_standard_runner_tag.png -- GPU-enabled SaaS runners on Linux]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/saas/linux_saas_runner.html#gpu-enabled-saas-runners-on-linux) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/358026).