# Using docker inside of docker with nvidia dependencies with Gitlab CICD

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I can use docker commands inside of my with using

```
services:
   - docker: 20.10.17-dind

image: docker:20.10.17
```

I can use

nvidia-smi and the nvidia tooling using an image using the runtime = "nvidia" configuration in my gitlab runner with.

```
[[runners]]
  name = "docker-runner-test"
  url = "<<REDACTED>>"
  token = "<<REDACTED>>"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "build_machine"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    runtime = "nvidia"
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    pull_policy = "never"
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
```

```
services:
   - docker: 20.10.17-dind

image: nvidia/cuda:12.1.0-base-ubuntu20.04
```

[How can I get use cuda inside a gitlab-ci docker executor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53647770/how-can-i-get-use-cuda-inside-a-gitlab-ci-docker-executor/53647771#53647771)

But what I need is docker command AND the nvidia tooling working in a container to build some images. I have tried simply installing the docker tools in `nvidia/cuda:12.1.0-base-ubuntu20.04` with the docker-entrypoint.sh example here https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/d45051476babc297257df490d22cbd806f1b11e4/19.03/docker-entrypoint.sh#L23-L29%20%20# but it seems to choke with

> ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Is there an easier way of doing this or a pre-built image I can use for this purpose?

Comment: Because you're using dind, it shouldn't be trying to use the default unix socket path... Try setting the variable `DOCKER_HOST` to `tcp://docker:2375` and `DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR` to an empty value.

Comment: I'd also try doing the opposite of what you already tried, meaning install your nvidia tooling in a new image  based on `docker:20.10.17`.